# gunicorn take long time to copy uploaded files

Tags: python, django, gunicorn

I try to deploy a django apps with nginx + gunicorn.

### my problem

gunicorn take a lot of time/proc/mem to copy a uploaded file into the local file system.

- time : 35sec to copy a 150Mb file
- CPU : > 95%
- memory : 50Mb

### the config:

- nginx is configued to use the [uploadprogress](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUploadProgressModule) module and the progress bar work fine.
- gunicorn is bound with a socket file (tryed with a tcp socket don't change anything)
- django 1.4 : don't do anything on this file (FileField) but copy on local FS

### what I tried :

runnning gunicorn alone in port 8050

- => no progressbar (of course since it is nginx how give this)
- => guncirorn take same time/mem/proc
- => the transfer take longer than with nginx but the finalization is faster :

  - nginx + gunicorn : transfer : 4sec, response generation : 30 sec
  - gunicorn : transfer : 30 sec, response generation : 4sec/
- => if in POST the file to a view that don't bother with POST, it take a little bit less time
  but > 25sec

is seem that gunicorn is weak when I ask he to transfer the file to the django apps.

### gunicorn cmd line (no config file)

gunicorn_django --user=www-data --group=www-data --workers=2 --bind 192.9.201.3:8050 -t 90 --name=TheName.domain.ltd